# string splitting from any character in a list

Tags: r, string

Is there a more elegant solution for the bottom code? Basically, I want to strsplit on a vector of characters. I want to know if there is a better solution such as with using %in% or something else.

```
data_d <- data.frame(id = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                     sentence = c('1. this is A sentence',
                                  '2. this is B sentence',
                                  '3. this is C sentence'),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)
listasd <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
data_d$first <- NA
for (i in listasd)
  data_d$first <-  ifelse(str_detect(data_d$sentence, i),
                          sapply(strsplit(data_d$sentence, i), "[", 1),
                          data_d$first)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe consider using the `stringi` package?

So maybe a little more elegant solution:

```
listasd <- c('C', 'A', 'B')
stri_split_regex(data_d$sentence, stri_paste(listasd, collapse="|"), n=2, simplify = TRUE)[,1]
```

It returns a vector of interesting parts of sentences without using `sapply`:

```
[1] "1. this is " "2. this is " "3. this is "
```

So you can make a solution without a loop, which is extremely slow in R:

```
data_d$first <- stri_split_regex(data_d$sentence, stri_paste(listasd, collapse="|"), n=2, simplify = TRUE)[,1]
```

Comment: data_d$first <- stri_split_fixed(data_d$sentence, c('C', 'B', 'A'), n=2, simplify = TRUE)[,1]
 the solution no longer works well. I guess it's assumed that you know ahead of time the order of the characters.

Comment: @user2340706 Please consider after edit. Regex version is used now, and stri_paste() for regex creation.

Comment: This is exactly it. Winner winner chicken dinner. Ty

Answer (score 0):

This gives the same output:

```
sapply(strsplit(data_d$sentence, c('A','B','C')),'[',1)
# [1] "1. this is " "2. this is " "3. this is "
```

According to `?split`, the `split` argument can take character vector which are recycled along `x`.

If you try:

```
sapply(strsplit(data_d$sentence, c('C','B','A')),'[',1)
# "1. this is A sentence" "2. this is "           "3. this is C sentence"
```

still works as there is nothing to split in the 1st and 3rd string.

Comment: Weird. This works with single letters, but it doesn't seem to work once the list includes 2 or more capital letters.

Comment: sapply(strsplit(data_d$sentence, c('C','B','A')),'[',1) this no longer works nicely.

Comment: Not sure what you mean it no longer works nicely since it produce the expected output. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `gsub`. The regex finds from a capital letter to the end of the line. If you have other capitals in your sentence, you'll need to adjust it.

```
data_d$first <- gsub('[A-Z].*$', '', data_d$sentence)

> data_d
  id              sentence       first
1  A 1. this is A sentence 1. this is 
2  B 2. this is B sentence 2. this is 
3  C 3. this is C sentence 3. this is
```

Comment: what does it mean to adjust it? What if the sentence is complex with title cases, etc? I'd be more interested in characters contained in a vector .

Comment: Well, if any of your sentences have more than one of the capital you're looking for, all of these approaches will have issues. If you only want to look for a single capital, you can loop this approach with `sapply(data_d$id, function(x){gsub(paste0(x, '.*$'), '', data_d[data_d$id == x,'sentence'])})`, but that loses the benefits of vectorization and is less elegant then the other answers.